# Beta sites have no "Top Questions" list

Tags: bug, beta-sites

On some beta sites, the "top questions list" on the home page is completely gone, both when logged in and logged out. This appears to have started happening in the last several minutes.

[Anime & Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Anime & Manga SE]

[Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Chess SE]